# Why does everyone except me have a Snorlax?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm level 21 and have been collecting and evolving my Pokemon into Gym-ready shape. Meanwhile I keep seeing players with these amazing Pokemon I've never even *seen* in the wild.

Nearly every gym near me has a Snorlax sitting at or near the crown.  I haven't even *seen* a Snorlax, let alone a Dragonite.

Where are people getting all these Snorlaxes? Should I be looking elsewhere?  Are there any special events I'm missing?

Comment: Well, what I can say from Personal experience: Selective Perception. Say every arena has 100 possible contester in a certain amount of time. Who will possibly be victorious? The guy with the snorlax? The guy with the dragonite? Or the guy with the pumped up Alakazam? Currently Snorlax and Dragonite are probably the strongest Pokémon, and if someone has one, he will put it in the arena. The other 99 guys will think that nearly everybody has a Snorlax, although it's just easier to spot a trainer with a Snorlax than to spot one without a Snorlax. Lvl 22 here, about 75 Poké's in, no Snorlax.

Comment: The more you walk around, the better your chances of finding one...

Comment: Good point. Sort of like when you buy a red car, suddenly you notice "everyone" drives a red car.  I think I already knew that, but was maybe hoping someone had a map to a secret Snorlax cave. Keep grinding I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### PokeVision

In the earlier days of the game, there were third party tools that showed you the exact spawn location of Pokémon and how long they'd be there. This allowed folks to easily locate rare Pokémon.

While I don't believe *everybody* has a Snorlax, it's just a perception as pointed out in other answers. However, players who started playing when these tools were available, have a higher probability of having more rare Pokémon.

#### Buy incubators

It's also possible that the folks who have hatched Snorlax, are spending loads of money on incubators, and walking off lots of eggs. Since they're hatching bunches of eggs, they have more chances to hatch rare Pokémon.

Through normal gameplay you always have an infinite use incubator, so you can always hatch eggs one at a time. Additionally, if you don't buy incubators, you'll receive limited use incubators as you level up. You'll receive your first 3 use incubator at level 6, another at level 10, and then one every 5 levels (10, 15, 20, 25...).  So if you're level 25 and never purchased any incubators, you would have only hatched 15 eggs from the free limited use incubators.  Whereas a trainer who's regularly purchasing incubators, could have hatched loads more Pokémon in the same timeframe.

#### Luck

It's also possible that some folks just got lucky.  When Niantic increased the rate of rare spawns, I caught a Snorlax the next day just down the street. Normally only Weedle, Pidgey, and Rattata spawn near my house, but one day a Snorlax just happened to pop up.

Answer (score 1):

Most people do not have snorlax. You say most people have them because you can see one at every gym. In a city with 10 gyms you see about 20 Snorlaxes defending them while the rest of the players did not see any. If you want one go for eggs you may be lucky enough to get one.

Answer (score 1):

No there are no special events of getting a Snorlax.

Here are some simple ways people get Snorlax:

1. Levelling up high (increases the chances of catching higher CP's)
2. Hatching more and more 10 Km Eggs: Snorlax's can hatch from 10 Km eggs
3. Or, they're simply lucky!

There's nothing special involved in getting a Snorlax. Just continue playing normally, and as you level up, you'll finally notice one in the wild or hatching out of one of your 10 km eggs.

Good Luck!

Comment: Do you have any reference source for #1?

Comment: @Sayse, Why would you need a source for it? Niantic isn't going to come and say that. That's from experience. You obviously aren't going to encounter a wild Snorlax when you're Level 5 or 10. It's been generally seen happening after you're atleast Level 15 and above. Though, if you still need someone to back that up, there are numerous threads on /r/pokemongo where people have added their experience about catching a Snorlax.

Comment: Of course you could encounter one at any level,  if it spawns for one it spawns for all. Just maybe with different cp.

Comment: Can confirm, #1 is completely false.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Leveling up high *does* increase your chances of catching **higher CP** Pokémon , however, it *doesn't* increase your chances of catching **rare** Pokémon.